# Moving from a page to another in php using ajax and jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have this my navigation bar and i would love to open the new pages without having to load the entire browser like default settings normally do.

How do i use ajax or jquery to do this

```
<div class="ms_top_right">
     <div class="ms_top_btn">
          <a href="upload" class="ms_btn upload">upload</a>
           <a href="javascript:;" class="ms_admin_name">{{ Auth::user()->username }}<span class="ms_pro_name">ns</span>                                                       </a>
          <ul class="pro_dropdown_menu">
        <li><a class="mobile-link" href="{{ route('logout') }}" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">Log Out</a>
    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST">
        @csrf
    </form>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

did this

```
<script>
    $('.ms_top_btn').click(function (event) {
    // Avoid the link click from loading a new page
    event.preventDefault();

    // Load the content from the link's href attribute
    $('.upload').load($(this).attr('href'));
});
</script>
```

But it did not work

Comment: I do not see any container with the `.upload` class where the http request response is being loaded. Then the `a hrefs` have to contain valid url routes so this would work.

Comment: @MarkSkayff how can display the url though after the page changed? and also use <a href></a> instead of <li></li>

Answer (score 0):

in your menu add onclick event

```
<ul class="pro_dropdown_menu">
    <li onclick="load_content('profile.html','Profile');" >Profile</li>
    <li onclick="load_content('manage_acc.html','Setting');" >Setting</li>
    <li><a class="mobile-link" href="{{ route('logout') }}" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">Log Out</a>
        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST">
              @csrf
        </form>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and call this function

```
function load_content(url, new_title) { 
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
      $('#your_content_div_id').html(data); // load html
      history.pushState('',new_title, url); // change url
   }
  });
}
```

or you can make a click event and then call by classname, and get url from the li and load it. but this is simpler.

or you can use load

```
  <ul class="pro_dropdown_menu">
  <li onclick="$('#your_content_div_id').load('profile.html');" >Profile</li>
  <li onclick="$('#your_content_div_id').load('manage_acc.html');" >Setting</li>
  ...
```

html should only contains content, no header footer or menu

to change the url without reloading use the following, you can put it in ajax

```
history.pushState('', 'New Page Title', new_url);
```

i hope it works

Comment: <div class="ms_top_right">
                     <div class="ms_top_btn">
                         <a href="upload" onclick="getPaging('upload')" class="ms_btn upload">upload</a></div></div>

Comment: and the url is not changing to the other page url

Comment: what does not work? and with ajax, the url dont change,

Comment: sorry i edit the ans,, load_content is the function name, which was wrong in the li

Comment: what if i want the url to display on the browser but not reload page.. how can i achieve this?

Comment: would it be like this <script> 
        history.pushState('', 'New Page Title', 'upload');
</script> then maybe  or how do i add it to the a href ?

Comment: now check , i have added title in the function param, so its passing to the function from li, and on success, it updating title, url,

Comment: now it changes but i need to press the <li> twice before it goes to actual page no way it can work using ahref because some websites use ahref

Comment: you can use a href, just put onclick="" in a tag, remove from li, and make href="#" or href='javascript:;'   
`<a href="#"  onclick="load_content('profile.html','Profile');" >Profile</a>`